# horizontal scrollbar issue for angular dataTables

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using angular dataTable where I need to provide horizontal scrollbar.

I used the following code to provide option to get horizontal Scrollbar.

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withDOM('scrollX', '100%');
```

But its not working. 
I didnt find any documentation to get horizontal scroll. Can anyone know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should call as follows to provide horizontal scrollbar:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('scrollX', '100%');
```

Comment: using .withOption('scrollX', '100%'); causes table header distorted

Answer (score 1):

```
DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
.withOption('responsive', true)
.withOption('scrollX', 'auto')      
.withOption('scrollCollapse', true)
.withOption('autoWidth', false);
```

will fix the header issue.

Comment: Thanks. this is really working with responsive tables

Answer (score 1):

Very Simple:

```
DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
.withOption("scrollX", true)
```